# Delayed bind on ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a typeahead directive that does not bind the typed text to the model while typing.

This is as such no problem, but I would like to use the ngModel directive for my binding so I am able to use something similar to

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.field" typeahead="sourceForTypeahead" />
```

instead of my current approach which works as a charm

```
<input type="text" ng-model="tmpFieldForInput" typeahead="sourceForTypeahead" typeahead-model="model.field" />
```

I can't figure if it is possible to change the "target" of ng-model internally in the directive so I get the typed input, and then is able to set the external model when an result from the source is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after looking into an old version of the checkbox-list module.

The solution is to change the ngModel attribute on compile time and make it point to an internal property in the directive and then compile in the postlink method.

I have updated the plunker for others to see the prototype: http://plnkr.co/edit/LbHH2pJGX1Iii8ZqqSie?p=preview

(Stack requires me to post code - so here is the )

```
app.directive('typeahead', ['$parse', '$compile', function ($parse, $compile) {
    return {
        priority: 1000,
        terminal: true,
        scope: {
            source: '=typeahead',
            ngModel: '='
        },
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            tElement.removeAttr("typeahead");
            tElement.attr("ng-model", "searchTerm");

            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $compile(element)(scope);
                // all my logic here
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ngModelOptions` to specify when you'd like to bind the input text to the model:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
<p>Hello {{myModel}}!</p>
```

There are different events you can trigger on, but in this case, the text will only be bound to the model once the end-user leaves focus from the field.

Additional resources: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: Also, you can check ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }". It's update model after 2 sec delay after typing. This thing is useful for typeaheads.

Comment: This will still bind "tes" to the model even though the source array contains  ["Test","Build"] 
Maybe a custom validation is the way to go, and then prevent submission of invalid data?
My biggest issue is that the source array might be more complex e.g. [{"name": "Test","id":1},{"name": "Build", "id":2}] and hence I want the user to select one of the complex values - but here I might be able to use setViewValue

Comment: And a $scope.$watch("myModel",function(newValue, oldValue){}) will still react on the "invalid" modelValue :/

Comment: @plazm Have a plunker by any chance? Without context I'm not sure how the array you're referencing plays into binding to ngModel. Feel free to send one over and I'll gladly take a look.

Comment: I have created a plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/LbHH2pJGX1Iii8ZqqSie?p=preview
As you will se, if you start typing "lov" it comes with suggestions, but the model is updated right away. I only want the model to be updated when enter is pressed, and with the object I currently log to the console.

Comment: If I type "lov" and press enter the suggestions array on line 27 in app.js is empty. Are there supposed to be suggestions at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Like @lux has mentioned, the right way to go about it is to use `ng-model-options`

But in your case, the ideal solution would be to do wrap your input in a form and bind on submit:

```
<form name="myForm">

<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }">
<p>Hello {{myModel}}!</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This will bind the value to the model only when you click your **Submit** button. This of course can be put anywhere you please.